# How does one change the path that Grammar-Kit's generated lexer Java file is generated into?

Tags: intellij-plugin, jflex, grammar-kit

How do I change the path that Grammar-Kit's generated JFlex lexer Java file is generated into?

I've asked on [Grammar-Kit's issue tracker](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/issues/96), but haven't received any response.

I'm tired of of the lexer not being put into my generated files directory (where I would be able to easily delete it along with all my other generated file, and exclude it from searches, and IDE warnings and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, got tired of of the lexer not being put into a generated files directory, so I skimmed through the plugin's source code to come up with an answer.

Grammar-Kit uses its own heuristic to decide where to stick your JFlex-generated lexer file, but that heuristic is obviously choosing wrongly in both of our cases.

**If you want your generated lexer to go in the generated folder, and Grammar-Kit isn't doing that, it's because the way that GK is designed, your `.flex` file cannot be inside a source root.** Of course, the `.flex` file *is* indeed a source file, but for GK's purposes it can't be marked that way — not if you want it to do the right thing and put its generated `.java` file into your designated generated folder **[1]**.

Instead, **move your .flex file out of any source folders, and into a content root that is not marked as a source directory**. GK should now behave *mostly* properly **[1]**. For it's own source file, the `.bnf` file, it doesn't behave this odd way; only with the `.flex` file.

**[1]**: *(actually, in my skimming, I think it may have looked like it's hardcoded specifically to go into a folder named 'gen', but I was only quickly skimming, so that may not be accurate. In either case, generating into a folder named 'gen' {the name most people choose for their generated folder anyway} should at least be sufficient, as your generated flex lexer will at least no longer be mixed in with your normal source files.)*

Comment: ^--- sadly, SO wouldn't let me address myself this in the answer :(